# Windows service serviceCredentials Invalid hexadecimal string format

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm debugging Win service. I have added some certificates on server. Trying to find certificate by its serial number.
https://gyazo.com/9cdcda75e98fe7b7c35496976a5aaaeb

The piece of behaviors.config:

```
  <serviceCredentials>
    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="DDBS.DDBSPasswordValidator, DDBS" />
    <serviceCertificate findValue="‎1C5411F9D38252824C2EC1CC7E5EBE3F" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
  </serviceCredentials>
```

I got error: Service cannot be started. System.FormatException: Invalid hexadecimal string format.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Used finding by FindBySubjectName option. Service works good.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. @richaux's answer should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 29):

From Jan Angelovič on [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/595f3f55-5dc0-4ec0-8f0b-f9c03540770a/cannot-findbythumbprint-invalid-hexadecimal-string-format?forum=wcf):

> If you cut and paste the [Serial Number or Thumbprint] 
>   from the common certificate dialog, it is copied in UNICODE
>   (UTF-16LE) encoding with special invisible control characters
>   (0xFF and 0xFE aka “Byte order mark“) on the beginning of the
>   string.

Personally, I saw this with the thumbprint; cut & paste from the dialog into Visual Studio kept 2 non-displayed characters (that could be "stepped through" with the cursor and deleted).

Comment: what do you suggest to overcome this issue? I am getting the serial number from that same dialog and it is not working.

Comment: paste into an editor of your choice and delete the invisible chars. Although they're invisible, you can detect their presence using the cursor.

Comment: What I did is to type it directly without copying and pasting, and it doesn't through and exception, but it can't find it either :S

Comment: I had this problem without noticing it. I opened it in Notepad++, then changed the Encoding to ASCII to see the problem...

Comment: Notepad++ encoding didn't work for me ... but I moved my cursor to the left of the string, and kept hitting delete till the hidden characters were removed (works in Visual Studio.)

Answer (score 6):

Remove all the **findValue="XXXXXXX"** and after that write it again.. sometimes the invalid char is after findValue="??? <--- here

Comment: this helped me. All I had to do was delete the first char in the string and the leading quote.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved with a slight addition to @richaux's solution. The *"Invalid hexadecimal string format."* exception persisted even after removing the spaces, or hand typing the thumbprint. I copied the line of code from VS 2019 to Notepad++ and this is what it looked like

*client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.Root, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "0f12c34c56fa78901234567e890af123ca45678d");*

Note the character  towards the end of the value string. This character was not visible in Visual Studio. I removed this character in Notepad++, and pasted the line copied from Notepad++ into VS 2019. Compiling and running this updated code removed the *"Invalid hexadecimal string format."* exception.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem after generating certificate using **OpenSSL utility** then installing on **Production server**.
The problem was when I checked serial number of certificate on **Production server**
it shows hex number with spaces this was causing error.

**The Solution** that worked for me is to first import the same certificate on your machine check its serial number (In my case it was without spaces value) then I copied that value and pasted on Production then it worked.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

@richaux is right, this are invisible characters. I copied the fingerprint from some Windows Dialog and had the same result.

To overcome this with c#, I replace the fingerprint-String with:

```
Regex.Replace(clientCertificateFingerprint, @"[^\w\.@-]", "",
                            RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
```